# Convert pandas dataframe to numpy array - which approach to prefer?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to convert a large dataframe to a numpy array.
Preserving only numerical values and types.
I know there are well documented ways to do so.

So, which one is to prefer?

```
df.values
df._as_matrix()
pd.to_numeric(df)
... others ...
```

Decision factor:

- efficiency
- safely operating on nan,np.nans, and other possible unexpected values
- numerically stable

Comment: Posters seem to have most problems when the dataframe contains mixed items and the dtype for a column, or the frame as whole is `object`.  It seems that pandas readily switches to `object` to accommodate strings and `nan` (floats).  `numpy` on the other hand uses `object` to handle sublists of varying size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The functions you mention serve different purposes.

1. [**`pd.to_numeric`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html): Use this to convert types in your dataframe if your data is not currently stored in numeric form *or* if you wish
   to cast as an optimal type via `downcast='float'` or
   `downcast='integer'`.
2. [**`pd.DataFrame.to_numpy()`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) (v0.24+) or [**`pd.DataFrame.values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html): Use this to retrieve `numpy` array representation of your dataframe.
3. [**`pd.DataFrame.as_matrix`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html): Do not use this. It is included only for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

Under the hood, a `pandas.DataFrame` is not much more than a `numpy.array`. The simplest and possibly fastest way is to use [`pandas.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

> `DataFrame.values`
>
> Numpy representation of NDFrame
>
> Notes
>
> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are
>   mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with
>   care if you are not dealing with the blocks.
>
> e.g. If the dtypes are float16 and float32, dtype will be upcast to float32. If dtypes are int32 and uint8, dtype will be upcast to
>   int32. By numpy.find_common_type convention, mixing int64 and uint64
>   will result in a flot64 dtype.

Comment: the precisation about dtypes is exactly the kind of warning I was looking for

Comment: Pandas 0.24 documentation says do not use .values() anymore, either .array or .to_numpy().  See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html, "In the past, pandas recommended Series.values or DataFrame.values for extracting the data from a Series or DataFrame. You’ll still find references to these in old code bases and online. Going forward, we recommend avoiding .values and using .array or .to_numpy()."

Comment: @ pauljohn32 could you make it an answer?very useful